# How to filter documents using a dynamic variable that depends on another document using Node.js and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I'm a bit stuck at this point... I need to add a new property to a document that varies according to the values of that same document and the values of another document. I set an example to make it better understood.

I have a Candidate Schema:

```
const CandidateSchema: Schema<ICandidate> = new Schema({
    role: {type: String},
    yearsOfExperience: {type: Number},
    compatibility: {type: Number} // Dynamic prop
});
```

And a Job Schema

```
const JobSchema: Schema<IJob> = new Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    postDate: {type: String},
    requirements: {
      role: {type: String},
      yearsOfExperience: {type: Number}
    }
});
```

Now I need to add to the candidate's "compatibility" property a new value based on the values of the candidate and a reference Job. This new property will be the compatibility between the Candidate and the requirements of the Job. In some cases I will need to find Candidates based on the compatibility property.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Relations are not quite clear. Could you add example candidate and job documents to illustrate how exactly  "new value" is "based on the values of the candidate and a reference Job". The example itself looks a bit confusing. It's hard to imagine a candidate with a single role and experience. On the job side plural "requirements" implies it is an array, could you confirm it is not.

Comment: You can use `$lookup` to count the no of matches in job for role and years of experience for each candidate. Not sure about your other ask `In some cases I will need to find Candidates based on the compatibility property.` - does that mean you are also looking to to persist compatibility property and perhaps update as jobs come and go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a [pre hook on save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre), and in this case something like:

```js
    CandidateSchema.pre('save', async function() {
      if(this.isModified('someothervalue'){
      const job = await JobSchema.find({'related job query'});
      this.compatibility = job.somevalue + this.someothervalue; //this is your current candidate
    }
    });

JobSchema.post('save', async function(job) {
      const candidates = await CandidateSchema.find({'related candidates query'});
      const candidateUpdates = [];
      candidates.forEach(candidate => {
          candidate.compatibility = job.somevalue + candidate.someothervalue; //this is your current candidate
          candidateUpdates.push(candidate.save());
    })
      await Promise.all(candidateUpdates);
    });
```

It may be a lot to process the above, but basically means that when you update a job, all related users ('related candidates query') get updated **after** a job is updated (normally you would need to check only if the fields that affect the users' `compatibility` are changed, but that's another thing), and the first hook just updates the user's `compatibility` when his fields that affect it are updated (like `someothervalue`).

Comment: I don't know if it's what I'm looking for... For example, I could use the pre hook to  find jobs filtered by compatibility? I need to include this new property when I make a query to DB to find candidates or jobs.

Comment: Yes, in the `const job = await JobSchema.find({'related job query'});` you can put whatever query object you want. So you can get the necessary job data to do your calculations, along with the current user's data, whenever you are updating him. Of course take into account that you need to do a `save()` on the document, and not a findAndUpdate or similar.